# Accessing local file phonegap outside the app

Tags: android, json, cordova

Today i've encountered the problem not getting access to my local storage on Android using Phonegap. Creating the directory and the file ain't a problem, however accessing the file is driving me crazy.

I've created the following directory in the root of my phone: "Hestia Brandpreventie"
Inside this directory I've created a file called "projects.json".

Can anyone tell me how I can access this .json file?

Code:

```
$.getJSON('file:///Hestia Brandpreventie/projects.json', function(json)
{
      console.log(json);
}
```

I suppose LocalFileSystem can help me with this?

Comment: I think this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) can help

Comment: My question was a bit uncompleted, i wanted to know if there is any option to fix my problem without the FileSystem from Phonegap. Seems like there isn't, so i'll fixed it the usual Phonegap way. Thanks anyway ;)!